# Neglecting the memory consumption, does it make a difference using `int` or `char`?

Tags: c++

Does it make a performance difference, if I use `int` or `char`? My guess would be no, because both are transmitted over the parallel bus to the ALU. Hence depending on the architecture, there would be no difference between any basic integers, whether `int8_t`, `int16_t` or `int32_t`, as long they are under the bitness of the system (32, 64, etc...). Im not exactly sure. Is this true?

Comment: I've actually found `int` arrays to perform better than `char` arrays in some cases. The memory bus fetches one word at a time, and if you're accessing something smaller than a word then it has to do extra work to only read or write the desired part of it.

Comment: I could imagine that alignment matters.

Comment: It depends on multiple factors.  Generally the performance difference would be negligible.  A char is "cheaper" to store and transfer, but there are apt to be some extra instructions (though cheap ones) used to (fairly often) switch back and forth between char and int if you try to use char exclusively (since many operations will be performed with int precision regardless).

Comment: (Net-net:  It's not worth it to try to "optimize" this, except in very special circumstances.  Rather, use what makes the most sense for the type of data you're dealing with.)

Comment: @BrianBi Is this just a subjective impression or something generally proved?

Comment: @s.bandara Could you please go in detail. I'm not a native english speaker, I dont know what you mean with alignment.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r switching from a `char` array to an `int` array made a program I wrote a few years ago about 10% faster. However, that program was very computationally intensive. I am pretty sure there's no detectable difference usually.

Comment: This is not answerable without knowing the target architecture.  Consider that a narrower processor may have to do multiple steps to manipulate even a 16 bit int.  While a wider processor may have to do extra masking operations to strictly implement a narrower type.

Comment: RISC processors can only do works in its native register size, hence anything smaller than that must be sign/zero extended. For x86 then some instructions doesn't allow anything registers other than Rxx or Exx, so you must also extend the number if it was stored in char/short. In addition, instructions that deal with byte or word in x86 may be longer in 32/64-bit mode and you'll don't want to work with it

Comment: Information about memory alignment is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering one variable, then the (native-size) integer code will always perform at least as fast, because no masking or alignment must be performed. However, if you considering arrays (or otherwise closely-packed sets of variables), then more of the smaller variables will fit in a cache line and be readily available to the core. Cache misses add significant latency that dwarfs the improved efficiency of manipulating the native-sized words in the core.